# Two-dimensional list comprehension Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'd like to know how I can convert the strings in a list to integers.

For example:

Input:

```
data = [
['1', '-160'],
['2', '-3000'],
['4', '-2'],
['5', '0.27'], ]

data = [int(a) for a in data[0]] #This converts only the first row of the list - I need the whole list converted 


print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[1, -160], [2, -3000],[4, -2],[5, 0.27]]
```

The reason to do this is because I want to sort the list but that doesn't work when the numbers have the apostrophes.

I hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct list comprehension:

```
[[float(c) for c in row] for row in data]
```

Please note that I have changed `int(...)` to `float(...)` to handle the floating numbers in your input. This gives as output:

```
[[1.0, -160.0], [2.0, -3000.0], [4.0, -2.0], [5.0, 0.27]]
```

As per your comment, if you have letters in your list, you can also add an `if` statement to your list comprehension:

```
[[float(c) if c.lstrip('-').isdigit() else c for c in row] for row in data ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
What can I do if I have letters in my list? 
For example:
data = [
['A', '-160'],
['B', '-3000'],
['C', '-2'],
['D', '0.27'], ]
How can they be ignored?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that all negative numbers are ignored. Do you have a solution for that as well? 
Thanks for your great help!!

Comment: Ok, found a solution by myself. [[float(c) if c.lstrip('-').isdigit() else c for c in row] for row in data ]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
['1', '-160'],
['2', '-3000'],
['4', '-2'],
['5', '0.27'], ]

print [[int(i), float(j)] for i, j in data]
```

Result:

```
[[1, -160.0], [2, -3000.0], [4, -2.0], [5, 0.27]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your issue (given that you want all values to be integers):

```
import math
...
result = [[math.floor(float(y)) for y in x] for x in data]
```

Result

```
[[1, -160], [2, -3000], [4, -2], [5, 0]]
```